# KeyError: 53 when using re module

Tags: python, nltk, python-re

I was trying to substitute every thing else with a blank using the code :

```
corpus_test = []
ps = PorterStemmer()
for i in range(len(texts)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',texts['title'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    corpus_test.append(review)
```

But I got the following error :

> KeyError: 53

Which is from the use of re module :

[image]

Comment: what does your texts variable look like?

Comment: Please put the entire stack trace in your question. The message has nothing to do with the regular expression. The immediate cause of the message is a dictionary lookup with the key `53`, probably at `texts['title'][i]`: In other words `texts['title']` is a dictionary and it does not contain the key `53`. Without more to go on it's hard to say more.

Comment: value `i` is created using  `len(texts)`, not `len(texts['title'])`. If `texts` is a list then better use `for item in texts: ... item ...`. But it seems it is dictionary and then better don't use it with `len()` because it can makes wrong result. So main problem is: what is in `texts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I was working with a csv file and I dropped some rows but I didn't reset the index, thus when we reach the iteration nb 53 i.e the index 53 we don't find it because it was dropped.

```
texts.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
```